# How can we load a .txt file with non aligned data into data frame in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, text, python-import

datafile (df) in .txt format  is mentioned below where few of the fields are missing for some records . The missing fields should be kept as blank in the respective columns .

For example - data file in txt format is

```
1,name=Messi,car=ford,Price=234,Bike=Harley  
2,name=Cavani,car=mazda,price=58,Bike=Ducatti  
3,name=Dembele,car=toyota,Bike=Yamaha        
4,name=kevin,car=Ford,price=989    
5,name=Aguero,Bike=Ducatti       
6,name=nadal,car=Ferrari,Bike=Harley
```

I want the file to be loaded to Python in the format below :
required output with respective column names:

[Output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhSx3.jpg)

I want the column names as Number, CARNAME , PRICE  , BIKENAME . I want the respective data to be populated in a DataFrame under the respective column names . The empty values should be kept as blank under the respective columns fields .

I am unable to post the image of the output or type the output here due to format issue . As I am new to stackoverflow , I don't have enough reputation to post the image

Please note that my dataset has million records.

Comment: Are you going to retain those `name=`, `car=` characters in the output DataFrame?

Comment: When the data doesn't fit a pandas import type, convert the data first. You could write an intermediate csv and use it.

Comment: Is the `5,name=Aguero...` on the same line as `4` or is it a typo?

Comment: You have name and car in the input but CARNAME in the output. How do those map?

Comment: Hi @BillHuang , No I do not want to retain name=, car= , I only need the values for the respective name

Comment: Hi @tdelaney , I tried to import the data into csv file  using delimiters , But as Some fields are empty in the  columns , The data  gets misplaced in the wrong column. For example : Some bike values can be found in the Column-Carname  (  number 5) OR Some Bike values  can be found in the Price column (number 3)

Comment: @AndrejKesely , It is a typo , I have changed it now . Thank you

Comment: @tdelaney, Both name and Carname are different Columns .

Answer (score 1):

There may be slim chance that an efficient library dedicated to process such a non-standard and non-uniform file format would exist. Therefore I will just parse this file manually line-by-line into a `list of dicts`, in which the missing keys (columns) can be taken care of by the `DataFrame()` constructor.

Code:

```
path_to_file = "/mnt/ramdisk/in.txt"
ls_dic = []
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        ls = line.split(",")
        dic = {}
        dic["Number"] = ls[0]
        for k_v in ls[1:]:
            k, v = k_v.split("=")
            dic[k.capitalize()] = v.strip()
        ls_dic.append(dic)

df = pd.DataFrame(ls_dic)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  Number     Name      Car Price     Bike
0      1    Messi     ford   234   Harley
1      2   Cavani    mazda    58  Ducatti
2      3  Dembele   toyota   NaN   Yamaha
3      4    kevin     Ford   989      NaN
4      5   Aguero      NaN   NaN  Ducatti
5      6    nadal  Ferrari   NaN   Harley
```

Comment: Hi @Bill Huang, Thank you , When I run the above command , I am getting the below error ,    
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-aa06f0b910ab> in <module>
      7         dic["Number"] = ls[0]
      8         for k_v in ls[1:]:
----> 9             k, v = k_v.split("=")
     10             dic[k.capitalize()] = v.strip()
     11         ls_dic.append(dic)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Please print out that line. Your data is corrupted. Some of the cells are not in the form of `name=value`, but I cannot debug what I can't see. And please note that this is already beyond the scope of the question itself, so you may have to customize the function according to the real situation.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Hunag. I appreciate your help  .

Answer (score 0):

You could write the data to an intermediate CSV. Add some file modification time checks and you get the conversion only when your data text file changes.

```
import io
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

header = ["Number", "CARNAME", "PRICE", "BIKENAME"]
key_to_index = {"car":1, "Price":2, "Bike":3}

def build_car_info_csv(in_fileobj, out_fileobj):
    reader = csv.reader(in_fileobj)
    writer = csv.writer(out_fileobj)
    for row in reader:
        outrow = [''] *len(header)
        outrow[0] = row.pop(0)
        for cell in row:
            key, val = cell.split("=")
            try:
                outrow[key_to_index[key]] = val
            except KeyError:
                # ignore unwanted keys
                pass
        writer.writerow(outrow)

def read_car_info_df(filename):
    filename = Path(filename)
    csv_filename = filename.with_suffix(".csv")
    mtime = filename.stat().st_mtime
    csv_mtime = csv_filename.stat().st_mtime if csv_filename.is_file() else 0
    if mtime > csv_mtime:
        with filename.open(newline="") as infile,\
                csv_filename.open("w", newline="") as outfile:
            build_car_info_csv(infile, outfile)
    return pd.read_csv(csv_filename)
```

**TEST**

```
open("mytest.txt", "w").write("""1,name=Messi,car=ford,Price=234,Bike=Harley
2,name=Cavani,car=mazda,price=58,Bike=Ducatti
3,name=Dembele,car=toyota,Bike=Yamaha
4,name=kevin,car=Ford,price=989    5,name=Aguero,Bike=Ducatti
6,name=nadal,car=Ferrari,Bike=Harley""")

df = read_car_info_df("mytest.txt")
print(df)
```